# SBS 2008 Duplicate Files - what can I delete

Tags: storage, windows-sbs-2008

I'm trying to look after my company's SBS 2008 server.  It keeps running out of space on the C: (OS)drive, so Exchange stops when it gets down to 4Gb free space.  From what I can tell after the last time I had a consultant in to fix it, there should comfortably be about 20Gb.

Running a duplicate files report gives me a huge list of duplicated files, and identifies just how much space they are hogging.  But my question is, which ones can I delete to recover the space?  Can I tell, from what's shown on the report, the files that are redundant and can safely be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Run WinDirStat and scan the C drive, find your largest files and start your cleanup there. There's no possible way that we can tell YOU what is safe to delete on YOUR server. Bring a consultant in if you're not comfortable.

Comment: thanks for you interest, but perhaps you can give me some additional guidance.  The C: drive on the server is OS only - all user data is on a separate partition (E:) - and I'm not concerned about duplications on that drive - there is plenty of room and it's easy to maintain because I know what all the files are.  But when I look at the Duplicate Files report for C: for instance, aspnet_perf.ini has 10 instances in folders with the same path except for ...\0000, ...\0001 etc, and all versions of the file were last accessed on the same day and time in 2009. Which ones can go?

Comment: It's completely subjective! Play it safe... have you run disk cleanup yet? Where is Exchange storing its logs for the mailbox store?